# How to overcome "object variable or with block variable not set" in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub bordersTest()
    Dim theRange As Range

    theRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This has been asked and thoroughly answered about 1.385e105 times all around the internet. Google? Look up the basics of variable usage in VBA and look at object variables. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="Object+variable+or+with+block+variable+not+set"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the variable:

```
Sub bordersTest()
  Dim theRange As Range

  Set theRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
  theRange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, it is working.